# method overloading with a parameterized type

Tags: scala

Just wondering if there is a way to call an overloaded method using a parameterized type. For example define the following object:

```
object Wrap {

        def f(x: X) = println("x called")
        def f(y: Y) = println("y called")
        def f(a: Any) = println("Any")

        def fp[T](t: T) = f(t)
}
```

When I test this making the following call

```
Wrap.fp(new X())
```

it goes to the call to the Any. Is there a way I can work it such that the appropriate f is called from fp()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def process[A](a: A) = a match {
  case c: X => Wrap f c
  case d: Y => Wrap f d
  case _ => Wrap f a 
}
```

Comment: Yes it can't really be done the way I wanted but a match expression is the best solution for me

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to do it:

First way assumes that `X` and `Y` are known types and not generic types. Then you could just do the following:

```
 def fp: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] ={
   case x: X => println("got x")
   case y: Y => println("got y")
   case _ => println("Any")
 }
```

and it would work very well without having to do much gymanistics.

Second way, use a type class:

```
 def fp[T](t: T)(implicit f: Caller[T]) = f(t)
```

That said, your type class will probably want to look like:

```
 trait Caller[T]{
   def apply(t: T)
 }
```

wherein you place the actual things in scope and use the order of resolution to find the final `Caller[Any]` so that every else takes precedence. So I'd have it be done like this:

```
 object Wrap{
   implicit val xCal = new Caller[X]{
     def apply(x: X){ println("x called") }
   }
   implicit val yCal = new Caller[Y]{
     def apply(x: Y){ println("y called") }
   }
 }

 object `package`{
   implicit val anyCal = new Caller[Any]{
     def apply(t: Any){ println("any") }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I wonder if the IDE has the second way as a quick fix refactor.

Answer (score 3):

Use a class tag for assisted matching:

```
scala> class W[A: ClassTag] { def f(x: X) = 1; def f(y: Y) = 2; def f(a: A) = 3; 
     | def g(x: Any) = x match {
     | case v: X => f(v); case v: Y => f(v); case v: A => f(v); case _ => -1 } }
defined class W

scala> trait Z
defined trait Z

scala> val w = new W[Z]
w: W[Z] = W@1685b453

scala> w g new X {}
res6: Int = 1

scala> w g new Y {}
res7: Int = 2

scala> w g new Z {}
res8: Int = 3

scala> w g "hi"
res9: Int = -1
```

In a real API, `g` would take a type parameter that is some supertype of the various params, because nobody writes API that takes `Any`.  The `T` param in the OP is basically `Any`, since it is unconstrained.

While I'm editing, we forgot to mention that overloading is evil.

Comment: @som-snytt why do you need to have a context bound on `A`? Even without `A: TypeTag` it will still work. Can you please explain it

Comment: @Jatin I wasn't paying attention. Thanks, I corrected the use case. I think I'll head over to the other answer and ask why they need a type param there.